# asp url change/edit

Tags: javascript, url, asp-classic

I have a page that uses 3dcarts software which is asp. I have page that dynamically loads images into a grid layout I have made. The code block 3dcart uses is */[thumbnail]* and I it loads */assets/images/theimageslocation_thumbnail.jpg* but that loads a small thumbnail image. I require a larger image and the original image from which that thumbnail is derived from is the same exact url but without the "_thumbnail" part. Is there a way I can remove the "_thumbnail" before the image loads or am I screwed?

Comment: Screwed? of-course not... do you want to remove the _thumbnail on the server or on the client?

Comment: I have no access to the server side code, so it must be client side.

`<a class="popupInfoLink" href="#popupInfo" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-popupurl="product.asp?itemid=[catalogid]"><img src= "/[THUMBNAIL]" style="max-height:300px;" alt="pot" border="0" /> </a>`

That is the code I have access to, and that is all. The `/[THUMBNAIL]` generates the url so I am assuming that I can only change it after it has already loaded? @Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic ASP/vbscript has a replace function, here's the syntax for replacing "-thumbnail" with nothing

```
replace(yourstringname,"_thumbnail","")
```

Comment: kay I am a little confused on implementing this into my code. <a class="popupInfoLink" href="#popupInfo" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-popupurl="product.asp?itemid=[catalogid]"><img src= "/[THUMBNAIL]" style="max-height:300px;" alt="pot" border="0" /> </a> Do I have to define the [THUMBNAIL] as my string first? Note I only have access to the code I have included here, 3dcart does not allow me to touch the asp pages.

Comment: Classic ASP is server side code, so no, you can't do this client side.  If you can't actually edit the Classic ASP then you probably should remove the Classic ASP tag from the question.  If there's a solution it almost certainly involves Javascript